# Trying to modify display of my url for html page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

What I would like to do is serve up a file such as "boat-repair" and have the url read allservicemarine.com/boat-repair/electrical-system-repair
Everything I have found so far seems to reference PHP files as part of the process is this possible with an html file and if so how can I potentially accomplish it

This code:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule    ^/?$    /boat-repair.html  [NC,L]
```

Will serve up the file when you type in allservicemarine.com
I tried putting the target file in a series of sub directories hoping the directory names would show in the address bar,but that still just pulls up the target file. I have been searching for many hours to try to find a solution and would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code I came up with:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule    ^/?$    /boat-repair/electrical-system-repair  [NC]
  RewriteRule    ^boat-repair/electrical-system-repair/?$    /index.html [NC]
```

The first rule tells the server to serve up: boat-repair/electrical-system-repair when the root directory is entered.

The second rule tells the server if the pattern: boat-repair/electrical-system-repair is matched to serve up index.html

The file served up (index.html) in the last step can be named anything you like as it will load, but not show in the address bar.

So after both rules are implemented you get: http://yoursitename.com/boat-repair/electrical-system-repair/ in the address bar, now I just need to figure out a way to remove the trailing slash.

These rules of course get put in the htaccess file.

In order for this to work you must have the folders named in the rules even if they are just dummy folders. If dummy folders be sure to put a text document in each folder named "DO NOT DELETE THIS FOLDER" so that six months down the road you do not look at these empty folders and delete them!